# Risk Neutral Pricing

Tags: stochastic-processes, finance, martingales

I'm studying risk neutral pricing and there's a thing I'm not understanding...
Let S be a process with the sequent dynamic $\frac{dS}{S}= \mu dt + \sigma dW^P$ where $P$ is the phisical probability.
Now, if I change the measure from $P$ to the risk neutral measure $Q$ and $r$ is the risk-free rate I obtain the dynamic
$\frac{dS}{S} = rdt + \sigma dW^Q.\\$
Now if I consider the new process $S^*=e^{-rt}S$, applying Ito's formula we obtain $dS^* = S^*\sigma dW^Q$ and this means that $S^*$ is a martingale, due to the fact it has no drift.
I don't understand why a Process with no drift is a Martingale...thank you very much!!!

Comment: I want to know why it's a martingale and how to use it in order to price derivatives, thank you again! ^^

Comment: ops...I think I have the answer...It's a Martingale not due to the fact that it has no drift but because $\frac{dS^*}{S^*}$ is a brownian motion and it is a martingale. Sorry guys :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A process $S$ is a martingale if $E_t\left(S_T|S_t\right)=S_t$.

Now, if $S^*$ is governed by the Stochastic Differential Equation

$$dS_t^*=\sigma S_t^*dW_t^Q$$

then

$$S_T^*=S_t+\int_t^T\sigma S_s^*dW_s^Q$$

Taking the expectation of $S^*_T$, we have

$$E_t\left(S_T^*|S_t\right)=S_t+\int_t^T\sigma E_t\left(S_s^*dW_s^Q|S_t\right)$$

whereupon using the [Law of Iterated Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation#Iterated_expectations_with_nested_conditioning_sets) yields

$$\begin{align}
E_t\left(S_T^*|S_t\right)&=S_t+\int_t^T\sigma E_t\left(S_s^*dW_s^Q|S_t\right)\\\\
&=S_t+\int_t^T\sigma E_t\left(E_s\left(S_s^*dW_s^Q|S^*_s\right)|S_t\right)\\\\
&=S_t+\int_t^T\sigma E_t\left(S_sE_s\left(dW_s^Q|S^*_s\right)|S_t\right)\\\\
&=S_t
\end{align}$$

Since $dW^Q$ has zero expectation.

Comment: thank you !!! could you tell me how could I use it in order to price a derivative with, let's say, F(S,t) as value...thank you! ^^

Comment: What derivative?  If the derivative is defined simply by a terminal payoff function $F(S_T)$, then the value $V_t$ of the derivative is $$V_t=e^{-r(T-t)}E_t^Q\left(F(S^*_T)|S_t\right)$$